# Static list instantiated every time it is called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding in C# and using Unity i'm having problems when using lists.

I have a static class where I keep data for using across scenes, there I have a GameObject list. Here is the code for that:

```
 public static class data {
     private static List<GameObject> objectsInScene;

     static sendsize() {
         objectsInScene = new List<GameObject>();
     }

     public static List<GameObject> ObjectsInScene
     {
        get{
            return objectsInScene;
        }
     }

     public static void addObject(GameObject obj)
     {
         objectsInScene.Add(obj);
     }
 }
```

And when I try to access the list it just returns null, even when I had filled it with GameObjects.

Also tried changing `private static List<GameObject> objectsInScene;` to  `private static List<GameObject> objectsInScene = new List<GameObject>();` and still returning null

I'm populating the list in this script (calling the add function with an event in the inspector):

```
   public class Add : MonoBehaviour {
        public void add(GameObject obj){
            GameObject objInstance = Instantiate(obj);
            sendsize.addObject(objInstance);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to access it in this script:

```
public class Setup3D : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {

        foreach (GameObject obj in data.ObjectsInScene) 
        {
            Instantiate(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to change private static List<GameObject> objectsInScene; to  private static List<GameObject> objectsInScene = new List<GameObject>(); and sendsize() should be either void or return a type

Comment: Do you call sendSize anywhere in your code ? Can you share some context around this code ?

Comment: Your second code sample references `data.ObjectsInScene`. This is not defined in your first sample, which only defines the private static `objectsInScene` field. As it stands, your second code sample should not even compile.

Comment: Could you show where and how you call addObject() to populate the List? also make sure this is happening BEFORE you try to access the list elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a little [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here. Here's the answer to the list being null.

```
public static class Data
{
    public static List<GameObject> ObjectsInScene = new List<GameObject>();

    public static void AddObject(GameObject obj)
    {
        ObjectsInScene.Add(obj);
    }
}

public class Setup3D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;

    void Start()
    {
        // Adding objects to your list
        GameObject objInstance = Instantiate(prefab);
        Data.AddObject(objInstance);

        // cycling through the list
        foreach (GameObject obj in Data.ObjectsInScene)
        {
            Instantiate(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to drag your GameObject prefabs into the GameObject slot in your inspector within Unity tho. Otherwise you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

The real problem here is that OP wanted to save instantiated GameObjects in a static list to be able to instantiate them again in another scene. You cannot do that because you are saving the **reference** to the GameObject. 
What you should do instead is saving the transform data of the objects and reinstantiate them in the other scene, then apply the transforms.
Like this :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Data
{
    public static List<DataStructure> ObjectsInScene = new List<DataStructure>();

    public static void AddObject(GameObject obj)
    {
        ObjectsInScene.Add(new DataStructure
        {
            position = obj.transform.position,
            rotation = obj.transform.rotation,
            scale = obj.transform.localScale
        });
    }
}

public class DataStructure
{
    public Vector3 position;
    public Quaternion rotation;
    public Vector3 scale;    
}

public class Setup3D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;

    void Start()
    {
        // Adding objects to your list
        GameObject objInstance = Instantiate(prefab);
        Data.AddObject(objInstance);

        // cycling through the list
        foreach (DataStructure obj in Data.ObjectsInScene)
        {
            var instantiated = Instantiate(prefab);
            instantiated.transform.position = obj.position;
            instantiated.transform.rotation = obj.rotation;
            instantiated.transform.localScale = obj.scale;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives a null reference exception at instantiation even though `Data.ObjectsInScene.Count` is 1

Comment: Why ? Could you elaborate ? 
the prefab GameObject should be a prefab from the assets folder, you should drag a reference to the prefab you want to instantiate in the inspector. If you don't do it then it is normal to have a NullRef.

Comment: Question is not mine i am just curious about the result. As i said i dragged the object and it is successfully added to list that is why my `Count` is 1 but i still can not access list elements. I can add even more elements but can not access them :)

Comment: nothing... still getting null when I call Data.ObjectsInScene

Comment: Really ? 
There is something else going on in your scripts then because I just copied and pasted the last piece of code I wrote into a new file called Setup3D.cs, created a new GameObject in hierarchy and assigned the script to this game object, then dragged a prefab into the ``prefab`` slot and It spawned me 2 copies of the prefab, as it should.

Comment: The thing is: I have a scene where I add the prefabs I want (while running), possition them and rotate them how I want. Then, when I press a button, it should spown them in another scene with the transformations I applied. The exact exception is: MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

Comment: Okay i understood the problem it works when you instantiate objects but it gives null reference exception  when you try to access any properties of the `obj` like `obj.gameObject.name`.

Comment: Typical XY Problem then : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem
You shouldn't save reference of your GameObjects if you want to pass them between scenes. Just save the position, rotation, and scale of your objetcs and assign them after you loaded the second scene.

Comment: Ok... and if I have various prefabs, how do I pass to the other scene which prefab to spawn?

Comment: Save the name of the prefab and get it after with Resources, or asset bundles. This might be a little more complex than what you tought at first... 
I'll edit my question with the answer to your list problem.

Comment: And, just to make it more complex... what if I'm spawning multiple copies of the same prefab?

Comment: Spawning multiples copies of a prefab houldnt be a problem at all, you just have to think a little bit more about your data structure and na,ming conventions then. I've edited my question with the answer to the actual question you asked :)

Comment: I;m not really sure if you can save prefab references tho. You should look this up because if you can then it's easier to get them after :)

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot